# Why is Openai's PPO2 implementation differentiable?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, backpropagation, proximal-policy-optimization

I'm trying to understand the concept behind the implementation of the OpenAI PPO2 algorithm. The loss function that is minimized is as follows: `loss = pg_loss - entropy * ent_coef + vf_loss * vf_coef`.

First question: The computation of `pg_loss` requires to use operations like `tf.reduce_mean` and `tf.maximum`. Are these two functions differentiable? Apparently, they are, otherwise, it would not work. Can someone explain why so I can understand the implementation?

Second question: During training, an action is sampled by using the Gumbel Distribution: Noise from such a distribution is added to the `logits` and then `tf.argmax` is applied. This index is then used to calculate the negative log-likelihood. However, the `tf.argmax` should also not be differentiable, so how can this work?

Comment: Please, edit your post to include a link to the implementation you're referring to.